# Switch Ruby Version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using Ubuntu 18.4
Here is ruby version which is installed in my server

```
root@vvv:/usr/share/redmine# rvm list
=* ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

as you see current version is 1.9.3

But when I install redmine system, I already get a log that

```
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
```

Maybe redmine also is using ruby 2.5.0

Can you help me how to switch from 2.5.0 to 1.9.3

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby`? Are you sure rvm ins installed/set-up correctly? I am also *suspicious* with the fact that you're running as root user -- the installation instructions (https://rvm.io/rvm/install / https://rvm.io/integration/sudo) state you should set up rvm "from a non-privileged user account", not as the root user.

Comment: Also... Are you *sure* that you want to be running ruby 1.9.3? It's very old, and support was dropped years ago. The latest version of redmine seems to support [at least ruby 2.7](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/20150), if not 3.0.

Comment: which ruby is "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby". I installed it as root user.

Comment: I want run ruby 1.9.3 because I want install Redmine 2.4.2. My server is died, when redmine 2.4.2 is running. I only have DB backup (SQL file) of Redmine 2.4.2.